# Passing arguments from controller to a method in 'app/lib'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using Rails without model and database. I have a controller that uses methods in `app/lib`:

```
def calculateDistance(lat,lng)
  ...
```

The method will return data in JSON format, and will be passed to the view.

I tried doing:

```
lat = params[10.0000]
lng = params[101.0000]
DistanceCalculation.calculateDistance(lat,lng)
```

I get an error:

[image: error]

What did I do wrong?

Comment: How's calculateDistance being defined?

Comment: exactly as written, def calculateDistance(lat, lng), and I read something about passing the argument as params, I've tried also. But it failed somehow.

Comment: What's the context, does the method belong to any particular class? to DistanceCalculation? if you have more code related to the problem, you could improve your question.

Comment: Yes, it belongs to class DistanceCalculation and inside it, has a methods of calculateDistance

Comment: are you sure it's not an instance method, e.g. DistanceCalculation.new.calculateDistance?

Comment: I have no Idea, because I never use the word `new` in Swift language. Do we have to?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do either:

Define the method as a class method:

app/lib:

```
def self.calculateDistance(lat,lng)
```

Or call it as an instance method:

```
DistanceCalculation.new.calculateDistance(lat,lng)
```